# Does Database snapshots work in SQL Server 2008 Developer

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2008, snapshot

We need to use SQL server snapshots for some automated tests and also for rollback purposes in case our Database Upgrades in Production systems goes bad. We were planning to use DB snapshots feature in SQL server 2008.

To be able to test all our processes and code in our development environment. We were trying to use it on SQL server 2008 developer edition which seems like it has all the features of enterprise edition but we ran into some problems with using DB snapshots.

Is this a feature that is really exclusive to Enterprise edition or do we need to make some setting changes to use this on Developer edition.

Comment: "but we ran into some problems with using DB snapshots" - what were the problems/errors?

Comment: What looked like an issue with editions was an issue else where in our scripts that were running in our Dev setup. sigh..
Thanks!

Comment: The Developer edition **IS** the Enterprise edition (in terms of feature set)

Answer (score 2):

I've had no issues using developer edition with snapshots - our unit tests use them to do more efficient data tier tests.

Comment: And this was on a regular install of Developer edition. Right? No special modules or settings that we might have missed?

Thanks!

Comment: Nothing special at all. We've found the only difference to enterprise is the licence.

Comment: That is actually the intended behavior. The Developer Edition is EXACTLY the same as the Enterprise Edition. This, of course to
1. Not have multiple Developer Edition licenses
2. Promote usage of Enterprise features encourage purchasing more expensive licenses.